# How to login with SQL Authentication using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I'm trying to connect via SQL Server Powershell Cmdlet (read **not ADO.NET**) using SQL-based Authentication, not Windows Integrated security.

Anyone know the format to use for this?

- Server: foo
- Instance: DEFAULT
- UserID: homer
- Password: simponsrock

**Edit:**
I can get to this SQL-cmdlet path using SQL Server Management Studio.

When doing it that way, the path is:
`SQLSERVER:\SQL\foo\DEFAULT+homer`

The problem is that I cannot `set-location` to this path via PowerShell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281947.aspx.

Your issue is dealt with in the section "Managing SQL Server Authentication Connections".

Answer (score 5):

You can also do a one-off using the Invoke-Sqlcmd statement.  You have to have the SQL 2008 Powershell host installed for this (sqlps.exe) which gets installed with SQL 2008.

```
PS C:\> sqlps
PS>invoke-sqlcmd -query "SELECT * FROM sys.databases" -serverinstance "foo" -username "homer" -password "simpsonsrock"
```